# linux superblock

Tags: linux, kernel

I'm newbie in linux programming and I have *silly* and simple questions. Suppose I have usb disk1 (/dev/sda1 - type vfat) and usb disk 2 (/dev/sdb1 - type vfat) and I mounted them in /tmp/media/myusbdisk/ as mount point

Are they have the same superblock? I'm confuse which one is superblock of usbdisk1 and usbdisk2

Answer (score 2):

Nothing is shared. When you mount a second filesystem to a given mount point, the kernel hides whatever was there first. So you see the contents of the filesystem that was mounted most recently, and any changes you make affect that filesystem.